CMD closes immediately on Windows 11
For a couple of months, I could not open the command terminal. It closes immediately (I see only a frame for a short time). I'm on Windows 11. I see there are background processes that use cmd.
I can do this in Powershell:
PS D:\> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3447]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
PS D:\>

I found the cmd in the Windows folder, but it also does nothing. I even don't know what details I should share here.
I cannot use Visual Studio, because it calls cmd.
I found only this, which says it is probably a virus. I've avast and it found nothing. How can I remove it, if it is a virus?

Create a new user. Does the problem persist?

Under the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor, do you have an item named autorun? If you do have it, better delete it.

@harrymc Please, write your comment in a reply, because it solved my problem and I want others to find this solution! And could you explain why it was there and why it was the problem? And no need reinstall Windows and configure everything again.

You can't imagine how happy I am right now. :-)

The solution was to use regedit to delete the string value named autorun within the following Registry key:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor


The autorun item contains one or more commands that are executed
by CMD when it starts
This item was perhaps added when you installed some product,
which was later perhaps uninstalled; you don't need to do anything
beyond deleting it 

See the article How-to: Autoexec commands
for more information about autorun and similar alternatives:

To run a command as soon as the Command Prompt is opened, this can be useful for loading DOSKEY macros:
Add an entry in either:

Registry (Current user):
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun


Registry (All users):
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun



This will also run if a CMD.exe session is initiated by drag and drop onto a batch file or by a FOR /F command which calls a sub-process.
The AutoRun entry can contain a string value [REG_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ] which will be executed. These AutoRun keys are rarely used and don’t exist by default.
Things not to do if you set a Command Processor AutoRun:

which outputs any text: that is likely to mess up any scripts using the FOR /F command.
to launch CMD.exe: that will recursively launch new CMD sessions until the machine runs out of memory.



I installed this in the past: http://mridgers.github.io/clink and now I'm pretty sure this caused the problem.
